# How can I add remove more number of objects at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is a bit long I'm not sure what I can reduce I will try.

When I'm running the program it's starting by making the square formation.

What I'm trying to archive is that at each time in runtime if I change the numberOfSquadMembers value up or down add/remove to each squad the more/less value of squad members.

Same for the numberOfSquads value.

The problem is I'm not sure how to do it in the Update() how to add more squads/squadmemebers or destroy when the values are less then the current ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Formations : MonoBehaviour
{
    enum Formation
    {
        Square, Circle, Triangle
    }

    [Header("Main Settings")]
    [Space(5)]
    [Range(4, 100)]
    public int numberOfSquadMembers = 20;
    [Range(1, 20)]
    public int numberOfSquads = 1;
    [Range(0, 4)]
    public int columns = 4;
    public int gaps = 10;
    public int circleRadius = 10;
    public float yOffset = 0;
    [Range(3, 50)]
    public float moveSpeed = 3;
    [Range(3, 50)]
    public float rotateSpeed = 1;
    public float threshold = 0.1f;
    public bool randomSpeed = false;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int randSpeedMin = 1;
    [Range(1, 100)]
    public int randSpeedMax = 1;
    public bool startRandomFormation = false;
    public string currentFormation;

    private Formation formation;
    private List<Quaternion> quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();
    private List<Vector3> newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private bool move = false;
    private bool squareFormation = false;
    private List<GameObject> squadMembers = new List<GameObject>();
    private float[] step;
    private int[] randomSpeeds;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool ready = false;
    private GameObject[] squads;
    private Vector3 startVector;
    private Vector3 total;
    private List<Vector3> endpositions = new List<Vector3>();

    public void InitFormations()
    {
        if (startRandomFormation)
        {
            formation = (Formation)UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Formation)).Length);
        }
        else
        {
            formation = Formation.Square;
        }

        squads = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Squad");
        for (int i = 0; i < squads.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (Transform squadMember in squads[i].transform)
            {
                squadMembers.Add(squadMember.gameObject);
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject unit in squadMembers)
        {
            if (unit != null)
            {
                total += unit.transform.position;
            }
        }

        Vector3 center = total / squadMembers.Count;
        //Vector3 endPos = GameObject.Find("Cube").transform.position;
        foreach (GameObject unit in squadMembers)
        {
            startVector = unit.transform.position - center;
            endpositions.Add(/*endPos + */startVector);
        }

        currentFormation = formation.ToString();
        ChangeFormation();

        randomSpeeds = RandomSpeeds(randSpeedMin, randSpeedMax, squadMembers.Count);
        step = new float[squadMembers.Count];

        ready = true;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        InitFormations();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (ready == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                randomSpeeds = RandomSpeeds(randSpeedMin, randSpeedMax, squadMembers.Count);
                foreach (int speedV in randomSpeeds)
                {
                    if (index == randomSpeeds.Length)
                        index = 0;

                    step[index] = speedV * Time.deltaTime;
                    index++;
                }

                ChangeFormation();
            }

            if (move == true)
            {
                MoveToNextFormation();
            }
        }
    }

    private void ChangeFormation()
    {
        switch (formation)
        {
            case Formation.Square:
                FormationSquare();
                break;

            case Formation.Circle:
                FormationCircle();
                break;

            case Formation.Triangle:
                FormationTriangle();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void FormationTriangle()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();

        int height = Mathf.CeilToInt((Mathf.Sqrt(8 * squadMembers.Count + 1f) - 1f) / 2);
        int slots = (int)(height * (height + 1f) / 2f);

        float verticalModifier = 1.25f;  // * 1.25f to increase horizontal space
        float horizontalModifier = 0.8f; // * 0.8f to decrease "vertical" space

        float width = 0.5f * (height - 1f);
        Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(width * horizontalModifier, 0f, (float)(height - 1f) * verticalModifier);

        int finalRowCount = height - slots + squadMembers.Count;
        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < height && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count; rowNum++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rowNum + 1 && newpositions.Count < squadMembers.Count; i++)
            {
                float xOffset = 0f;

                if (rowNum + 1 == height)
                {
                    // If we're in the last row, stretch it ...
                    if (finalRowCount != 1)
                    {
                        // Unless there's only one item in the last row. 
                        // If that's the case, leave it centered.

                        xOffset = Mathf.Lerp(
                                rowNum / 2f,
                                -rowNum / 2f,
                                i / (finalRowCount - 1f)
                                ) * horizontalModifier;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    xOffset = (i - rowNum / 2f) * horizontalModifier;
                }

                float yOffset = (float)rowNum * verticalModifier;

                Vector3 position = new Vector3(
                        startPos.x + xOffset, 0f, startPos.y - yOffset);
                newpositions.Add(position);

            }
        }

        move = true;
        formation = Formation.Square;
    }

    private Vector3 FormationSquarePositionCalculation(int index) // call this func for all your objects
    {
        float posX = (index % columns) * gaps;
        float posY = (index / columns) * gaps;
        return new Vector3(posX, posY);
    }

    private void FormationSquare()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationSquarePositionCalculation(i);

            //squadMembers[i].transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y);
            squadMembers[i].transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));

            //newpositions.Add(new Vector3(transform.position.x + pos.x, 0, transform.position.y + pos.y));
            newpositions.Add(new Vector3(endpositions[i].x + pos.x, 0, endpositions[i].y + pos.y));
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = true;
        formation = Formation.Circle;
    }

    private Vector3 FormationCirclePositionCalculation(Vector3 center, float radius, int index, float angleIncrement)
    {
        float ang = index * angleIncrement;
        Vector3 pos;
        pos.x = center.x + radius * Mathf.Sin(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.z = center.z + radius * Mathf.Cos(ang * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        pos.y = center.y;
        return pos;
    }

    private void FormationCircle()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        Vector3 center = transform.position;
        float radius = (float)circleRadius / 2;
        float angleIncrement = 360 / squadMembers.Count;//(float)numberOfSquadMembers;
        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)//numberOfSquadMembers; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationCirclePositionCalculation(center, radius, i, angleIncrement);

            var rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(center - pos);

            if (Terrain.activeTerrain == true)
                pos.y = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(pos);
            pos.y = pos.y + yOffset;
            newpositions.Add(pos);
            quaternions.Add(rot);
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = false;
        formation = Formation.Triangle;
    }

    private void MoveToNextFormation()
    {
        if (randomSpeed == false)
        {
            if (step.Length > 0)
                step[0] = moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            squadMembers[i].transform.LookAt(newpositions[i]);

            if (randomSpeed == true)
            {
                squadMembers[i].transform.position =
            Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                squadMembers[i].transform.position =
                Vector3.MoveTowards(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i], step[0]);
            }

            if (Vector3.Distance(squadMembers[i].transform.position, newpositions[i]) < threshold)
            {
                if (squareFormation == true)
                {
                    Vector3 degrees = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                    Quaternion quaternion = Quaternion.Euler(degrees);
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternion, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    squadMembers[i].transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(squadMembers[i].transform.rotation, quaternions[i], rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static int[] RandomSpeeds(int min, int max, int howMany)
    {
        int[] myNumbers = new int[howMany];

        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
        {
            myNumbers[i] = UnityEngine.Random.Range(min, max);
        }

        return myNumbers;
    }
}
```

This is the script that generate the squads and number of squads members first time :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SquadsGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject squadPrefab;
    public int numberOfSquads;
    public int numberOfMembersInsquad;

    private GameObject squadsParent;

    private void Start()
    {
        squadsParent = GameObject.Find("Squads");
        GenerateSquads(numberOfSquads, numberOfMembersInsquad, squadPrefab);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public void GenerateSquads(int squadsCount,
        int numberOfMembers,
        GameObject squadMemberPrefab)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < squadsCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject newSquad = new GameObject();
            newSquad.name = "Squad " + i;
            newSquad.tag = "Squad";
            newSquad.transform.parent = squadsParent.transform;

            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfMembers; x++)
            {
                var go = Instantiate(squadMemberPrefab);
                go.name = "Member " + x;
                go.tag = "Squad Member";
                go.transform.parent = newSquad.transform;

                switch (i % 6)
                {
                    case 0: ColorSquad(go, Color.green); break;
                    case 1: ColorSquad(go, Color.red); break;
                    case 2: ColorSquad(go, Color.blue); break;
                    case 3: ColorSquad(go, Color.yellow); break;
                    case 4: ColorSquad(go, Color.cyan); break;
                    case 5: ColorSquad(go, Color.magenta); break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ColorSquad(GameObject squad, Color color)
    {
        Renderer rend = squad.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.material.SetColor("_Color", color);
    }
}
```

Update :

What I have tried so far :

I added this part to the Update()

```
if(oldNumOfSquadMemebers != numberOfSquadMembers)
        {
            var tt = numberOfSquadMembers - oldNumOfSquadMemebers;
            for (int i = 0; i < tt; i++)
            {
                var go = Instantiate(squadMemberPrefab);
                squadMembers.Add(go);
            }

            oldNumOfSquadMemebers = numberOfSquadMembers;

            FormationSquare();
        }
```

The problem now is in the FormationSquare method :

```
private void FormationSquare()
    {
        newpositions = new List<Vector3>();
        quaternions = new List<Quaternion>();

        for (int i = 0; i < squadMembers.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 pos = FormationSquarePositionCalculation(i);

            squadMembers[i].transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -90, 0));

            newpositions.Add(new Vector3(endpositions[i].x + pos.x, 0, endpositions[i].y + pos.y));
        }
        move = true;
        squareFormation = true;
        formation = Formation.Circle;
    }
```

Now I'm making a new instance for the newpositions List so each time I change the number of squad members there are more members but less newpositions so at some time I'm getting out of index exception.

If I don't make a new instance for the List then it will work but then after some time it will throw the out of index exception this time because it keep adding more and more new positions to the list.

So this newpositions List I'm stuck with it. Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: How are you loading these squads initially? I would use UnityEngine.Instantiate and UnityEngine.Destroy to create/destroy objects at runtime. You can instantiate a prefab by giving UnityEngine.Instantiate's first parameter a game object returned by reference or by Resources.Load.

Comment: @SirTrashyton I updated my question with the small script that create first time the squads and the number of members in each squad. The script SquadsGenerator.

Comment: @SirTrashyton instantiate and destroy is the way the problem is how to maintenance keeping the current formation/s when adding or removing the squads/squads members.

Comment: @SirTrashyton This is the two scripts I'm using for now the Formations and the SquadsGenerator.